# User access and roles in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

I want to set up a portfolio where all projects names will be my epics and every individual project will have their own space where they will manage thier pbis..now my question is how can I control the user access in my parent space ..like what access and roles I should give to each pm in the parent epic spac

Answer (score 0):

For each project that you create, the system creates the followings project-level groups. These groups are assigned project-level permissions.

The full name of each of these groups is [{project name}]{group name}. For example, the contributors group for a project called "My Project" is [My Project]\Contributors.

[image]

For your PM, they should be assigned Project Administrators permission.

> **Project Administrators**
>
> Has permissions to administer all aspects of teams and project,
> although they can't create team projects.
>
> Assign to users who manage user permissions, create or edit teams,
> modify team settings, define area an iteration path, or customize work
> item tracking.

Members of the Project Administrators group are granted permissions to perform the following tasks:

- Add and remove users from project membership
- Add and remove custom security groups from a project
- Add and administer all project teams and team-related features
- Edit project level permission ACLs
- Edit event subscriptions (email or SOAP) for teams or project-level
  events.

As for Access levels, it grant or restrict access to select web portal features.  Access levels enable administrators to provide their user base access to the features **they need and only pay for those features**. They should as least owe **Basic** access level.

For more detail info, please refer our official doc here:

- [Project-level permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#project-level-permissions)
- [About access levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops)